# pg_dumpall excluding some tables

Tags: postgresql, database-backups, pg-dump, pg-dumpall

I want to get a full backup of postgres 9.6. Including the users and permissions. However I want to exclude some tables. In `pg_dump` there is an option for excluding some tables (`-T`). However in `pg_dumpall` there are no such options.

Is there a way for getting a backup like this in a single command? Or should I get `pg_dumpall` (without tables) and `pg_dump` with `-T`? However in the second scenario these two dumps are not completely synchronised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use `pg_dumpall -g` and `pg_dump -T`.

True, the dumps will not share a single snapshot, but unless you add, modify or delete users and tablespaces very frequently, that should not be a problem in practice.

Comment: Does `pg_dumball -g` contain user permissions on tables? Or is this included in `pg_dump`? Or not at all?

Comment: I found this option in `pg_dump`: `--no-privileges` Therefore I think by default `pg_dump` includes privileges.

Comment: `pg_dumpall -g` will only dump users and tablespaces, no permissions on database objects.

Comment: Are my thoughts on `pg_dump` including permissions (when `--no-privileges` is not used) true?

Comment: Yes, pg_dump dumps *everything* necessary to create a perfect copy of the database, so it also contains `GRANT` statements.